# how to create a custom searchbar with flutter same this with Flutter Code

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gofS.png)

I want create a serachbar

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
 return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
  body: Center(
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 300,
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text('Your Data'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[50],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Add Name',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Your Result-> [image]